# Android - Display Int onClick with Buttons [Error: Cannot resolve method ‘display(int)’ ]

Tags: java, android

I am getting a error on Android Studio as what i believe is because I'm inserting multiple 'displays'. Can someone advise & explain what I need to do and why it causes this error so I know for future?

Please see below for the following error:

```
package com.example.android.justjava;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

/**
* This app displays an order form to order coffee.
*/
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/**
* This method is called when the order button is clicked.
*/
public void submitOrder(View view) {
int quantity = 2;
display(quantity);
displayPrice(quantity * 5);
}
/**
* This method is called when the increment button is clicked.
*/
public void increment(View view) {
int quantity = 3;
display(quantity);
displayPrice(quantity * 5);
}

/**
* This method is called when the decrement button is clicked.
*/
public void decrement(View view) {
int quantity = 1;
display(quantity);
displayPrice(quantity * 5)


/**
* This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
*/
private void display(int number) {
TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(
        R.id.quantity_text_view);
quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
}

/**
* This method displays the given price on the screen.
*/
private void displayPrice(int number) {
TextView priceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);
priceTextView.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number));
}
}
```

Comment: Your method `decrement` seems to be missing its closing bracket, that's why the other methods don't know the private methods. But: There should be an error in your IDE!

Comment: Increment always sets the quantity to 3? It doesn't simply add 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
* This method is called when the decrement button is clicked.
*/
public void decrement(View view) {
int quantity = 1;
display(quantity);
displayPrice(quantity * 5)   // <--- Missing ';' character
```

You missed the (;)character